# Twitter Bootstrap - how to display active/selected item

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

What is the "standard" way to signify a selection/active item of a let's say `<li>` in an `<ul>` using Twitter Bootstrap? I have a list of items and want to have only one to be selected at a time.

Comment: What do you mean by selected?

Comment: Like an active row or record in a grid. There's a list of items, and when the user picks one of them I want a visual feedback on that. And preferable I want Bootstrap to handle that there's only one selection possible.

Comment: apply an `active` class to `li`. Relevant selector/markup: `.nav-list > .active > a, .nav-list > .active > a:hover {` applies a style to `ul.nav-list li.active a`; if that's what you mean

Comment: yeah ended up with exactly that but then I have to manually remove this active rule before I mark other items active :( but thanks anyway  why not answer it so I can accept?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> apply an active class to li. Relevant selector/markup: .nav-list >
>   .active > a, .nav-list > .active > a:hover { applies a style to
>   ul.nav-list li.active a; if that's what you mean –

Ross 17 hours ago